# Pointing to the wrong position in doubly linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

My doubly linked list has two dummy nodes, head and tail. The `addToFirst` function works perfectly for me, but when I trying to use the same algorithm with `addToBack`, it keeps printing the dummy node for me. Why does this happen?

```
DList *init( )
{
   head = ( DList * ) malloc( sizeof( DList ) );
   if ( head == NULL ) {
      prtError( "Insufficient memory!" );
      return( NULL );
   }
   
   tail = ( DList * ) malloc( sizeof( DList ) );
   if ( tail == NULL ) {
      prtError( "Insufficient memory!" );
      return( NULL );
   } 
     
   head->data = -1;
   tail->data = -1;   
   head->next = tail;
   head->prev = NULL;  
   tail->next = NULL; 
   tail->prev = head;
   return ( head );  /* indicates no error */ 
}

/* print function */ 
void prtList( )
{
   DList *p;
   for ( p = head->next; p != tail; p = p->next )
        printf( "%4d", p->data );
   printf( "\n");
}

DList *insertFirst( int d )
{
                
   /***** ADD YOUR CODE HERE *****/
   DList *first = ( DList * ) malloc( sizeof( DList ) );
   printf("FF");
   if ( first == NULL ) {
      prtError( "Insufficient memory!" );
      return( NULL );
   }
   /* 2. put in the data  */
    first->data = d;
 
    /* 3. Make next of new node as head and previous as NULL */
    first->next = (head)->next;
    first->prev = NULL;
 
    /* 4. change prev of head node to new node */
    if ((head) != NULL)
        (head)->prev = first;
 
    /* 5. move the head to point to the new node */
    (head)->next = first;

   return first;        // replace this line with your code
}

DList *insertLast( int d )
{

   DList *last = ( DList * ) malloc( sizeof( DList ) );
   printf("LL");
   if ( last == NULL ) {
      prtError( "Insufficient memory!" );
      return( NULL );
   }
   /* 2. put in the data  */
    last->data = d;
 
    /* 3. Make next of new node as head and previous as NULL */
    last->prev = tail->prev;
    last->next = NULL;
 
    /* 4. change prev of head node to new node */
    if ((tail) != NULL)
        (tail)->next = last;
 
    /* 5. move the head to point to the new node */
    (tail) = last;
    //if I try with (tail)->prev = last; then the outputs were empty.


   return last; // replace this line with your code          

}
```

Expect Result:

```
LL  5
LL  5  10
LL  5  10  15
LL  5  10  15  20
LL  5  10  15  20  25
LL  5  10  15  20  25  30
LL  5  10  15  20  25  30  35
LL  5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40
LL  5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
LL  5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
FF   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
FF  10   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
FF  15  10   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
FF  20  15  10   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
FF  25  20  15  10   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
FF  30  25  20  15  10   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
FF  35  30  25  20  15  10   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
FF  40  35  30  25  20  15  10   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
FF  45  40  35  30  25  20  15  10   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
FF  50  45  40  35  30  25  20  15  10   5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
```

My Result:

```
LL  -1
LL  -1   5
LL  -1   5  10
LL  -1   5  10  15
LL  -1   5  10  15  20
LL  -1   5  10  15  20  25
LL  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30
LL  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35
LL  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40
LL  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
FF   5  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
FF  10   5  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
FF  15  10   5  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
FF  20  15  10   5  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
FF  25  20  15  10   5  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
FF  30  25  20  15  10   5  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
FF  35  30  25  20  15  10   5  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
FF  40  35  30  25  20  15  10   5  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
FF  45  40  35  30  25  20  15  10   5  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
FF  50  45  40  35  30  25  20  15  10   5  -1   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
```

Comment: Please show a [mre] with inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Not the main problem , but I see some problem with `void prtList( )` you are using `p = head->next;` and  `p->data`, what about `head->data`

Comment: I am not allowed to change the print function. :C

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes here. I would recommend you to brush through the fundamentals again.
Here is a quick fix to your code. Make sure to understand each change.

````
DList *insertFirst( int d )
{
                
   /***** ADD YOUR CODE HERE *****/
   DList *first = ( DList * ) malloc( sizeof( DList ) );
   printf("FF");
   if ( first == NULL ) {
//      prtError( "Insufficient memory!" );
      return( NULL );
   }
   /* 2. put in the data  */
    first->data = d;
 
    /* 3. Make next of new node as head and previous as NULL */
    first->next = (head)->next;
    first->prev = head;
 
    head->next->prev=first;
    (head)->next = first;

   return head;        // replace this line with your code
}

DList *insertLast( int d )
{

   DList *last = ( DList * ) malloc( sizeof( DList ) );
   printf("LL");
   if ( last == NULL ) {
//      prtError( "Insufficient memory!" );
      return( NULL );
   }
   /* 2. put in the data  */
    last->data = d;
 
    /* 3. Make next of new node as head and previous as NULL */
    last->prev = tail->prev;
    last->next = tail;
    tail->prev->next=last;
    tail->prev=last;
   return head; // replace this line with your code 
}```
````

Comment: Thanks, this code works for me, and I am trying to figure out the logic in it. :D

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is being introduced through your dummy elements. I've worked more with singly linked lists than bidirectional lists. But in that case I have a head pointer that is not part of the list. And when the list is empty it's null. Which requires special case code to check for when the head of the list is null on each insertion. Since insertion is slightly different then.

So my inclination for you case would be to have a head and tail which both start out null. Then when the first element is added head and tail are set to point to the same single element. And the next and prev would of the element would be set to null. Since there is no element before or after.

However, I think there's a cleaner solution for bidirectionally linked lists (what is often referred to as a doubly linked list). In that solution there's a single "dummy" entry. Which acts as both the head and tail. so *pDummy->next refers to going forward to the first element and *pDummy->prev refers to going backwards to the last element. So at initilization pDummy->prev and pDummy->next both point to pDummy. So an empty list actually has one element pDummy, which is treated as both then beginning and end of list marker. So if any pItem->next == pDummy then pItem is at the end of the list. If pItem->prev == pDummy then pItem is at the head of the list.  I believe this solution is the faster implementation and easier to implement. Since inserting at the beginning doesn't require checking for an empty list, since pNext already points to the next element in the list instead of being null.

Since I suspect this is a coding exercise I haven't written the code for you. Instead helped with the logic involved.